# How to add Expand/Collapse to a nested Gridview without using JQuery

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Is it possible to add expand colapse functionality in a nested grid view without using Jquery  or java script.

If yes can someone give me an example?

Below is the asp code for my nested gridview

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    BackColor="White" BorderColor="#E7E7FF" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" 
    CellPadding="3" GridLines="Horizontal" 
    onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" DataKeyNames="id1" >
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id1") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Students">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
                    GridLines="None">
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
                    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
                    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
                    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
                </asp:GridView>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#B5C7DE" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#4A3C8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#F7F7F7" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#E7E7FF" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#E7E7FF" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#F7F7F7" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F4F4FD" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#5A4C9D" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D8D8F0" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#3E3277" />

</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: its impossible to do it without using javascript. ajaxcontroltoolkit also use javascript for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the asp.net ajax toolkit.  Which still uses javascript, but you don't have to do any of it yourself.  It's all done under the hood.

http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.devexpress.com

Here is the collapse/expand panel extender

http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.devexpress.com/CollapsiblePanel/CollapsiblePanel.aspx